# How to return in list of values display value in apex

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

How to Add to a Database Table the Exact Date and Time, Adding a New Record to this Table

In List to value needs to be TWO columns in the output of your query. The value in position 1 is the DISPLAY VALUE (what is shown in the selection dialogue that uses it.) And RETURN VALUE (what is actually returned as the input value to the page item that shows the options from the query.

I want the table to write the value that is in the list, not some other, so can you do ??

select id,name from SEC_DATA_area

I want select name,name from SEC_DATA_area

Answer (score 0):

The first row of text confuses me a bit, but I think you are looking for the SQL query for List Of Values where the display and return are different.
Its:

```
SELECT name as d
      ,name_id as r
  FROM table
```

The d stands for display and r for return. You can skip the naming of the columns as long as they are in this sequence, first select column is display, second is return(saves into table).

I hope I understood your question correctly and answered it appropriately.